# How can I sort two fields in the Table, that one name corresponds to one date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can I sort two fields in the Table, to remove double names for one date. I need formula. I know one way, is to convert date to the text type and then to concatenate these fields (A2&B2) and then remove duplicate with Button "Remove duplicates". But my data changes dynamically from csv and I don't want to remove duplicate manual every time. Thanks.

My example of file is here: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AgfvDQ65okq09H4ZfOCrSrNZPtXT?e=aQnZTU

[image]

Comment: You could make a concatenated column and then either use the unique formula or something like [this](https://exceljet.net/formula/extract-unique-items-from-a-list) if you have an older version of excel

Comment: Unique formula - good idea. I'll try

Comment: I just found out there is no FILTER function in usual Excel 2020, only in Office365. It's very very sad who work with dynamic data:(((. The second - this function is very convenient and clear for understanding. There is no also Unique.

Comment: You could use a VBA macro and trigger it either manually with a button on the worksheet; or using event-code.

Comment: I posted a link for a workaround to create a unique formula in older version of excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to use just `UNIQUE` to concatenate two or more ranges and remove duplicates:

```
=UNIQUE(A2:A10 & B2:B10)
```

(Example 3 in link)

- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/unique-function-c5ab87fd-30a3-4ce9-9d1a-40204fb85e1e

Comment: Unfortunately I use standalone Offcce2019 (not Office365). This function great, I know.

Comment: You  should migrate - Microsoft365 is a big improvement. https://www.microsoft.com/en-GB/microsoft-365

Comment: I would love, but our company can't.

Answer (score 0):

As *Hooded 0ne* advised me I did the next:

1. Formula for C2: **=TEXT(A2;"dd.MM.yyyy")&B2**        *[to concatenate date we need to convert it to the text type]*
2. Formula for D2: **=IF(COUNTIF($F$2:$F2; $F2)>1; "Duplicate"; "Unique")**
3. Sort D Column by text filter containing Unique
4. And if you want your table updated dynamically in any changes with TextFilter add Macros for the Sheet:

   Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   Sheets("SheetName").AutoFilter.ApplyFilter

   End Sub